# how to set spacing between items and border color for items in ListView control(using C++ and win32api)

Tags: c++, winapi

I successfully created thumbnail images using ListView control in win32 api and c++(No MFC).

I am struck up in proceeding with the below mentioned tasks.

I dont know what macros and styles to be applied to achieve the below tasks in listview control.

->how to align the items in listview control(LVS_LIST style)?

->how to set spacing between the items in listview control?

->how to set Border and border color for items in listview control and it should be highlighted on selecting the item in listview control.?

->After inserting the items in listview control,i have set vertical scroll bar but i get it as horizontal scroll bars.how to solve this also?

someone help me to achieve these tasks.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please see this set of window styles suitable for `LVS_LIST`:

[List-View Window Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774739(v=vs.85).aspx)

What about border color - consider `LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED`.

And extended styles - [Extended List-View Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774732(v=vs.85).aspx)

Yet you can subclass window procedure for this control to manage [`LVM_GETITEMRECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761049(v=vs.85).aspx), [`LVM_GETITEMPOSITION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761048(v=vs.85).aspx), [`LVM_SETITEMPOSITION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761192(v=vs.85).aspx) messages differently.

And have a look over: [NM_CUSTOMDRAW (list view) notification code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774865(v=vs.85).aspx)

Yet don't forget to call [`InitCommonControlsEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775697(v=vs.85).aspx) function before creating the ListView window.

Comment: @Zorgeiv 
Thanks.
I have clearly mentioned using LVS_LIST which is list view(style).
I need to align the items,set spacing b/w items and border color in listview control.I have mentioned in my question.
please help me to achieve the tasks mentioned in my question.

Comment: It can be combined with other styles.

Comment: can you be little more specific for each of my question what styles  to set.

Comment: CreateWindowEx(..., "ListBox", WS_CHILD | ... LVS_LIST | LVS_ALIGNLEFT | LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED, ..., /*EX_STYLES*/ ...);

Comment: i have tried explicitly with this macro ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyleEx() but could not get any changes.

Comment: What exactly you tried to set and what exactly you want to do with it?

Comment: Please paste your entire ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyleEx() call here.

Comment: ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyleEx(hWndListView, LVS_EX_AUTOAUTOARRANGE | LVS_EX_BORDERSELECT, LVS_EX_AUTOAUTOARRANGE | LVS_EX_BORDERSELECT);

Comment: As a second argument you are free to pass zero. For these flags to work you have you use Vista or later. So InitCommonControlsEx call is mandatory.

Comment: ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle this one is much simpler.

Comment: InitCommonControlsEx -> INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX -> dwICC -> ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES

Comment: @zorgeiv iam  using everything what you have been saying.
can you tel for spacing b/w items in listview control what i should use.

Comment: What do you mean by stating spacing? Is it a distance between list items o maybe it's a distance between the text and a rect boundaries? In all cases please consider LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED style if you want to somehow override default list painting behavior.

Comment: You can also use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bb775091(v=vs.85) macro to set indentation if this what you are looking for.

Comment: @zorgeiv 
Yes it is a distance between items in listview control.
but LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED style suited only for Report view not for list view.

Comment: @zorgeiv I also need to draw border to an item and assign border color to it so that it gets highlighted when i select an item in listview control.

Comment: Did you try ListView_SetOutlineColor macro along with setting LVSS_EX_BORDERSELECT ex style?

Comment: Nevertheless NM_CUSTOMDRAW notification must be sent to your parent window if you don't even use LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED.

Comment: And yet don't forget to add manifest to your application - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx or make manifest tool generate it for you. As far as I know visual styles have to be manually applied to manifest.

Comment: but i need vertical spacing between items in list view style

Comment: After inserting the items in listview control,i have set vertical scroll bar but i get it as horizontal scroll bars.how to solve this also?

Comment: Apply WS_VSCROLL style along with LVS_LIST.

Comment: Try to override NM_CUSTOMDRAW in order to specify different item rects for spacing.

Comment: Consider using SetWindowTheme for a bit of beautification.

Comment: I believe this article may be helpful for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @zorgeiv thanks

let me try out and implement and i ll get back here.

Comment: Was this answer helpful?

Comment: Yes Thanks for your help it helped me to understood a lot

Comment: Maybe you can mark my answer as an answer then? It's the typical use case on stack overflow.